# Cannot access Selenium IDE commands on right-click

Tags: selenium, firefox, ide, command

I'm using Selenium IDE 2.9.1 to automate my regression test cases.

Normally when running Selenium IDE in Firefox, if you right-click on a browser element - whether it's text, a button, a field, etc. - a list of potential commands comes up. This had been the case for me as of last week.

This morning, however, I'm finding that right-clicking in the browser does not show the commands anymore. This is making writing my test scripts a lot slower.

Can anyone tell me why this might be happening, and/or how to fix it?

A similar question was asked (Can't see Selenium IDE commands on mouse click), but it was never answered. So I'm asking here.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem - no "Show all available commands" when right clicked on object. A downgrade to firefox to 50.1.0 helped.